# implement singleton design pattern and use it throughout classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, design-patterns

I have a console app where I solved one algorithm in it.
I had all the logic in program.cs file, but then I was asked to implement Object Oriented design, and use separation of concerne more.
So I started separating my logic in different classes, but in program.cs I had 4 global variables that I would use in my logic to solve the algorithm.

Now I have separated these 4 global variables and I've put them in a single class. What I need is to use these fields, in the same way as I had in my program.cs
I need to use these 4 global variables throughout the classes and methods, where I assign different values to them.

I have tried to implement Singleton design pattern, as I thought this would suit my case, because I would instantiate the class only once, and I would store these values to use them in different moments, with their specific values.

So basically I would need one class to be instantiated only once, and to be used  throughout other classes but also to preserve the values as I would with global variables.

This is my code

class cars.cs

```
public void ForbidenConfig(int number)
{
    Collections c = new Collections();
    Wheels3 w3 = Wheels3.GetInstance; // here I get the instance of the class

    int k = 1;
    Configurations[] block = new Configurations[number];
    for (int i = number; i > 0; i--)
    {
        Console.Write("Test case " + k + ": ");
        //bla bla bla another logic here
        

        //below I want to add data to collections
        w3.Collections.Add(block[k - 1]);
        k++;
    }
    c.AddCollections(object1, object2);
}
```

Now I have also this other class collections.cs where I have this code

```
public void AddCollections(CarsConfigurations config, CarsConfigurations previousConfig)
{
     Cars w3 = Cars.GetInstance; // here I get the instance of the class
    if (CheckConfiguration(config) == false)
    {
        config.SetPreviousState(previousConfig);

        //below I also add data to another field of the singleton class
        w3.AddCollections2.Add(config);
    }
}
```

now this is my singletton class

```
public void AddCollections(CarsConfigurations config, CarsConfigurations previousConfig)
{
     Cars w3 = Cars.GetInstance; // here I get the instance of the class
    if (CheckConfiguration(config) == false)
    {
        config.SetPreviousState(previousConfig);
        w3.AddCollections.Add(config);
    }
}


 public sealed class Cars
{
    private static List<CarsConfigurations> ConfigCollections = new List<CarsConfigurations>();
    private static List<CarsConfigurations> ClosedStateCollections = new List<CarsConfigurations>();
   
    
    private static Cars instance = null;
    public static Cars GetInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Cars();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Cars()
    {
        List<CarsConfigurations> ConfigCollections = new List<CarsConfigurations>();
        List<CarsConfigurations> ClosedStateCollections = new List<CarsConfigurations>();
    }
    public static void ConfigCollection()
    {
        return this.ConfigCollections; // this line gives me an error ofcourse,  Member 'Cars.ConfigCollections' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead 

    } 
    
}
```

Can I achieve what I'm looking for with Singleton design pattern..? If yes how can I manage it?
Is there any other way?
Can you guys please help me, I have this task to deliver, and I'm really out of time!
Can you give any other ideas?

I would really really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your constructor is all messed up. You declare two variables with the same name as your static fields and then throw them away once the constructor completes. Remove the content/body of the constructor and remove the `static` next to your two list fields. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

> I was asked to implement Object Oriented design

In that case, a glorified set of global variables doesn't address that concern. The [Singleton design pattern has its uses, but not like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67331100/126014).

Instead, as a start, pass the variables around as method arguments:

```
public void AddCollections(
    CarsConfigurations config,
    CarsConfigurations previousConfig,
    Cars w3)
{
    if (CheckConfiguration(config) == false)
    {
        config.SetPreviousState(previousConfig);

        w3.AddCollections2.Add(config);
    }
}
```

Once you've done that, you may want to consider if further modelling is possible. For example, the above method has both `Cars` and two `CarsConfiguration` objects. Would it make sense to somehow combine those two classes?